# The maximum number of lock requests has been reached for the database in DB2

Tags: db2

My database has LOCKLIST and MAXAPPLS set to unlimited.  But still I get the above error while trying to open the files (around 100 files of nominal size) from an application running on a Unix machine. The locks limit of the Unix machine is also set for unlimited.

Message:[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0912N  The maximum number of lock requests has been reached for the database.  SQLSTATE=57011

Comment: `MAXAPPLS` or `LOCKLIST` cannot be "unlimited"; consider increasing the `LOCKLIST` value. `MAXAPPLS`, open files, or Linux `ulimit` have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Sorry... it is not unlimited ... it is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

add `WITH UR` at the end of your SQL queries, this allow to read an uncommieted transactions on DB2, also avoid transactions on READ only queries